# Using react context not working as expected in remix react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, remix.run

Despite having seen working examples of this in non remix projects, it doesn't seem to work in the way I'm implementing it?

I have the following in `root.tsx`:

```
    export const MyContext = createContext("default");
    function Document({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
      return (
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <Meta />
            <Links />
          </head>
          <body className="root-body">
            <MyContext.Provider value="bonjour!">
              <Header />
            </MyContext.Provider>
            {children}
            <ScrollRestoration />
            <Scripts />
            <LiveReload />
            <Footer />
          </body>
        </html>
      );
    }

    export default function App() {
       return (
         <Document>
           <Outlet />
         </Document>
  );
}
```

In my `<Header/>` component I have:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { MyContext } from "~/root";

    export const Header = () => {
              const result = useContext(MyContext);
              console.log(result);
              return(null)
              }
```

The result is then that `"default"` is printed to the console, but surely from my understanding it should be `"bonjour"`?

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The output on the server console is from Remix SSR. It does appear that the context is not being applied during server rendering. However, it does show up correctly after hydration. Unfortunately it also results in hydration errors (see browser console).

Anyway, that does seem odd. My understanding is that you can use most hooks server side (except for `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`).

https://codesandbox.io/s/remix-react-context-mzexmt